# Skip wrapping elements when deserializing XML with C# / .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize incoming XML data with C#/.NET 3.5 using a class hierarchy that starts with a class tagged as `XmlRoot` and contains classes and members with the required attributes. This works so far.

Now I have come across input data that looks approximately like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:foo xmlns:ns1="http://some.name/space">
  <ns1:bar>
    <payload interesting="true">
      <stuff type="interesting"/>
    </payload>
  </ns1:bar>
</ns1:foo>
```

The outermost two elements - `ns1:foo` and `ns1:bar` - are results of the serialization process in the remote system that I have no control over. They always exist in exactly the same constellation and are of no interest whatsoever.

Following my current approach, I could write a `class Foo` that references a `class Bar` which in turn references the `class Payload`. However, since I'm not interested in the `foo` and `bar` elements, is there a way to skip them during the deserialization and have the Deserializer return only the payload? If not: Is it possible to make a `class FooPayload` with an `XmlRoot(ElementName = "foo", Namespace = "http://some.name/space")`attribute, but then somehow skip the `bar` and `payload` levels so that the `FooPayload` class directly contains properties named `Interesting` and `Stuff`?

Comment: Have you considered using LINQ over the XML first (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx) and then serializing that object?

Comment: @Ruskin: No, not yet - is this technology available as of .NET 3.5?

Comment: @vwegerl: Yup, it's been available for a while.  You will definitely find it useful to prune the original XML and then run your standard serializer over it.  I don't know about performance though. (NB: I am reluctant to write the solution :))

Answer (score -2):

I modified your XML to correct for errors.  See interesting solution below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<ns1:foo xmlns:ns1=\"http://some.name/space\">" +
                  "<ns1:bar>" +
                    "<ns1:payload interesting=\"true\">" +
                      "<ns1:stuff type=\"interesting\"/>" +
                    "</ns1:payload>" +
                  "</ns1:bar>" +
                "</ns1:foo>";

            //remove prefix
            string pattern = "(</?)([^:]*:)";
            Regex expr = new Regex(pattern);
            input = expr.Replace(input, "$1");

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
            StringReader s_reader = new StringReader(input);
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(s_reader);
            Foo  foo = (Foo)xs.Deserialize(reader);
            foo.GetStuff();
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "foo")]
    public class Foo
    {
        [XmlElement("bar")]
        public Bar bar { get; set; }

        private Boolean interesting;
        private string type;

        public void GetStuff()
        {
            interesting = bar.payload.interesting;
            type = bar.payload.stuff.type;
        }

    }
    [XmlRoot("bar")]
    public class Bar
    {
        [XmlElement("payload")]
        public Payload payload { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("payload")]
    public class Payload
    {
        [XmlAttribute("interesting")]
        public Boolean interesting { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("stuff")]
        public Stuff stuff { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("stuff")]
    public class Stuff
    {
        [XmlAttribute("type")]
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: The XML arrives exactly as shown, with mixed qualified and un-qualified elements. Otherwise, this is exactly what I have described ("I could write..."), with some unnecessary and potentially dangerous raw XML mangling through regexes.